# Fluent NHibernate Mapping for Table in multiple Many-to-Many Relationships

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'am trying to set Fluent NHibernate mappings for the Database shown below:

```
 Campaign Table
 Id
 Name

Category Table
Id  
Campaign_id
Name

Customer Table
Id
Name
Phone
...

SalesMan Table
Id
Name
Phone
...

CustomerSalesManCategory Table
Id
Customer_id
SalesMan_id
Category_id
```

The CustomerSalesManCategory table's columns has as foreignKeys the Primary Keys of Customer,SalesMan,Category respectively.

A Campaign has a one to many relationship with Category

A Customer has a many to many relationship with Category

A Customer has a many to many relationship with SalesMan  but also is related with the Category

That is:A customer is assigned a SalesMan for a specific Category and as a result a correct entry in the CustomerSalesManCategory Table should perfectly reflect that(all 3 id's populated)

With the mapping i currently have,entries are inserted in the CustomerSalesManCategory with NULLS on SalesMan_id or Category_id-which is correct for the mappings I provided.

However,i cant figure out the mappigns for having FluentNhibernate do the job correctly done..Single entrty in CustomerSalesManCategory table on SaveOrUpdate for Customer.

Any help is very much appriciated.
Here are my current Mappings:

```
 public class CampaignMap : ClassMap<Campaign>
{
    public CampaignMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.CreationDate);
        HasMany(x => x.CampaignsCategories).Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

  public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
       Id(x => x.Id);
       Map(x => x.Extension);
       References(x => x.Campaign);
       HasManyToMany(x =>         x.CustomersAssginedInCategory).Inverse().Table("CustomerSalesManCategory");           
    } 
}

public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.CallingName);
        Map(x => x.OfficialName);
        Map(x => x.Year);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.CustomerCategories).Table("CustomerSalesManCategory");
        HasManyToMany(x => x.CustomerSalesMen).Table("CustomerSalesManCategory");
    }
}

 public class SalesManMap : ClassMap<SalesMan>
{
    public SalesManMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
       Map(x => x.Name);
       Map(x => x.Email);
       Map(x => x.Phone);
       Map(x => x.Description);
       HasManyToMany(x => x.CustomersAssignedTo).Inverse().Table("CustomerSalesManCategory");           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a three way association is typically a Dictionary

```
// in Customer

public IDictionary<SalesMan, Category> asd { get; private set; }

// in CustomerMap
HasManyToMany(x => x.CustomerSalesMen)
    .Table("CustomerSalesManCategory")
    .AsEntityMap("SalesManId");
```

Comment: Thanx very much for the reply- I used the free version of the  Entity Developer Tool and within the classes it created,an intermidiate class was used.That's the CustomerSalesManCategory Class.This class had a Customer a Category and a SalesMan object to initiliaze.I moved on from there.